# Find complex solutions

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Find all solutions of the equation $4\sin(z) + 5 = 0$.

So $4\sin(z) + 5 = 4\sin(x+iy) + 5 = 0$. Hence $\sin(x+iy) = \frac{-5}{4}$. So $x+iy = \sin^{-1}(\frac{-5}{4})$ which gives us $x+iy =$ ...

I am not sure what is really being asked here or how to achieve it. Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start, recall that $\sin{z} = \frac{1}{2i}(e^{iz}-e^{-iz})$. So we are looking for $z$ such that 
\begin{equation}
e^{iz}-e^{-iz} = -\frac{5i}{2}.
\end{equation}
Multiplying both sides by $e^{iz}$ and bringing all terms to the left yields
\begin{equation}
(e^{iz})^2+\frac{5i}{2}e^{iz}-1=0.
\end{equation}
Setting $w = e^{iz}$, we have the quadratic equation
\begin{equation}
w^2+\frac{5i}{2}w-1=0.
\end{equation}
If the solutions to this equation are $w_0$ and $w_1$, then you are now looking for $z$ such that $e^{iz}=w_0$ or $e^{iz}=w_1$. From here you can use logarithms, which presumably you have learned, to solve for $z$.

Comment: Good answer. +1 for you. @Nicholas: And don't forget that when you apply $\log$, you get a multivalued answer with an arbitrary $2\pi k i$ added--that's where the periodicity shows up.

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle\sin z=-\frac54$

$\displaystyle\cos z=\pm\sqrt{1-\frac{25}{16}}=\pm\frac{3i}4$

Using [Euler formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerFormula.html), $$e^{iz}=\cos z+i\sin z=\pm\frac{3i}4+i\left(-\frac54\right)=-\frac{(5\mp3)i}4=-2i\text{ or }-\frac i2$$

Comment: @Nicholas, how about this?